# How can $C^1([a,b])$ be complete in the face of Stone-Weierstrass theorem?!

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

There exists continuous, nowhere differentiable functions that are, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, approximated by polynomials. So, a sequence of polynomials, which are obviously $C^1$ functions, are converging to a function that is not $C^1,$ but $C^0$. So, how is it that $C^1$ is a Banach space?

I'm not asking someone to prove that $C^1$ is complete at all, I'm asking why the conditions I specified do not directly contradict the completeness.

Comment: In what topology (metric or norm) you should specify?

Comment: $||f||^1 = \sup|f| + \sup|f'|.$

Comment: The Stone Weierstrass theorem asserts that a continuous function can be approximated _uniformly_ by polynomials. Uniform convergence corresponds to convergence in the $C^0$ topology, or $\sup $ norm. The space $C^1$ is, consequently, not complete with respect to this norm. This does not imply that it is not complete with respect to the $C^1$ norm (it actually is).

Comment: Okay, so the space of $C^1$ functions is not complete with respect to the $C$ norm? That makes a little more sense. I'm still struggling to understand why $C^1$ can be complete in any norm if sequences of $C^1$ functions converge to non-$C^1$ functions.

Comment: Convergence always depends on the norm. A sequence may converge wrt one norm but not the other norm. There are sequences of polynomials converging to non-smooth functions in the $C^0$-norm, but those *don't converge* in the $C^1$ norm.

Comment: The sequence that converges in one norm need not be convergent in another norm. Even more correct is to say: The sequence that is Cauchy in one norm need not be Cauchy in another norm. Whatever example you have in mind is Cauchy in C norm but not in C1 norm. It is more demanding of a sequence to be Cauchy in C1 norm than it is in C norm bc you also need the derivatives to remain close throughout. Check your example to see!

Comment: We are used to the fact that no matter what two norms you put on a finite dimensional vector space, a sequence converges in one of those two norms if and only if it converges in the other. But this lovely property breaks down for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'd rephrase your last sentence as: "Lovely: this property breaks down for infinite dimensional vector spaces!" :P

Comment: The $C^1$ norm implies that the derivative is Cauchy hence converges to something (in $C[0,1])$). The only tweak is relating the something to the function underlying the derivative.

Comment: But, even in the $C^1$ norm, can't you construct a sequence of $C^1$ functions that converges to only a $C^0$ function?

Comment: No, you can't. Because $C^1$ is complete. If a sequence converges in that norm, then the limit is also $C^1$.

Comment: "But even in the $C^1$-norm, can't you construct a sequence of $C^1$ functions that converges to only a $C^0$ function" - no. That's what @copper.hat pointed out. If you have a $C^1$ Cauchy sequence, it will converge to a $C^1$ function, in the $C^1$ norm. There is a bit of an effort needed to prove this, but it's a standard result and discussed in most real analysis textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Still weird to me, but I guess there must be something intrinsic about the structure of the $C^1$ norm that somehow "stops" certain sequences of polynomials from converging to a $C^0$ function under the $C^1$ norm. Do you have any insight on what that mechanism might be?

Comment: Here is a proof :-) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920098/27978

Answer (score 1):

I will condense the discussion in the comments into an answer. Scroll to the end if you want the actual mechanical explanation. The rest is a general explanation of why we shouldn't expect spaces with different norms to act the same.

First things first, we have to speak about a few general observations and facts.

A metric space $(X,d)$ is a set $X$ with a metric $d$. In particular, the same set $X$ with different metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ defines *different* metric spaces. They may not even share a single relevant feature except their cardinality. The circle, the disc, the Euclidean plane, the line, and Euclidean space are all completely different metric spaces. But *all* of these spaces can be defined using the same set, since they have equal cardinalities. Take a bijection $f:\mathbb R\to M$, where $(M,d)$ is any of those metric spaces, then the metric space $(\mathbb R,f(d))$ is isomorphic to $(M,d)$ as a metric space, meaning that it has essentially the same structure. So we can define completely different metric spaces on the exact same set using different metrics. And you may already notice: some of these are complete (the circle, the line, the plane, 3d space), while others are not (the disc). This is because the underlying *set* has no influence on the metric space except supplying a cardinality. But metric spaces of equal cardinality can behave wildly differently.

Your question deals with normed spaces $(V,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ instead of metric spaces, but for any norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ the function $d(x,y):=\Vert y-x\Vert$ is a metric, and so the same thing as above applies to normed spaces, too: a different norm on the same vector space may lead to completely different normed spaces. The only dangerous thing is that this doesn't apply to finite dimensional normed spaces, so we may be lulled into a false sense of security while using only finite dimensional spaces, to then be surprised when everything goes back to normal in infinite dimensional spaces.

Anyway, we deal with the following infinite dimensional normed spaces: $(C^0,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0),(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0),(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$, where I always shorten $C^n([a,b])$ to $C^n$. The norms are given by $\Vert f\Vert_0:=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\vert f(x)\vert$ and $\Vert f\Vert_1:=\Vert f\Vert_0+\Vert f'\Vert_0$.

Now Stone-Weierstraß says that in $(C^0,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$ the subspace $(P,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$ of polynomial functions is dense. Since $(P,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)<(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)<(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$, where $<$ means "is subspace of", we also get that $(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$, as an intermediate space between a subspace and its completion, must also be dense in the superspace, and thus not complete (since complete spaces are never dense in proper superspaces). This is what you observed.

However, $(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$ is *not* an intermediate space between $(P,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$ and $(C^0,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$. It doesn't even have the same norm! It may behave completely differently to $(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$. And thus the theorem that $(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$ is complete has no bearing on the observations about $(C^1,\Vert\cdot\Vert_0)$.

But you wanted to know about a mechanism that suppresses convergence of polynomials to non-smooth functions in the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$. So I'll give you that as well, though without proof. Convergence of a sequence $f_n$ in $ \Vert\cdot\Vert_0$ means that starting at some $n$, $f_n$ and the limit function $f$ are close to each other on their whole domain. This is because $\Vert f-f_n\Vert_0$ measures the largest difference between $f$ and $f_n$ on their whole domain. Now if this is the only requirement, then polynomial sequences can converge to non-smooth functions. But if we look at the derivatives $f'_n$ of such a sequence, we will notice that this new sequence $f'_n$ will not converge in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_0$. It's not even Cauchy. So to forbid sequences of polynomials from converging to non-smooth functions, we can erect an additional barrier and introduce a *new* kind of convergence ($C^1$-convergence) in which we require *both* $f_n$ *and* $f'_n$ to converge in the old sense ($C^0$-convergence). We can force this by introducing the norm $\Vert f\Vert_1$, which is the sum of the $C_0$ norms of $f$ and $f'$. So if this norm is small, then both the function and its derivative are small, which is a stricter requirement than only having the function itself be small. And a Cauchy sequence in this norm will require not only the functions themselves to get ever closer to each other, but their derivatives, too! It's this last bit that stops convergence to non-smooth functions.